# SQL query for extracting a single row from multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, orm

We had a table previously for user information which contained the pinHash as well

| id | userId | seed | assetType | pinHash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | a12H | Bitcoin | q23es |
| 2 | 111 | r23s | Bitcoin | e2w12 |
| 3 | 111 | y36w | Ethereum | e2w12 |

So, for the same userId the pinHash would be same for all the assetTypes.

Now, we are migrating to another table

| id | userId | pinHash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | q23es |
| 2 | 111 | e2w12 |

Which SQL can be used to get all the records with for this migration i.e. distinct userId with pinHash.

N.B: I already did this migration using spring boot where I take all the rows from the first table and then use a HashMap to put only one row of userId in the new table. Still, I would love a SQL for which only distinct userId rows would come as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always want to report the minimum `id` from each set of duplicates, we can use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, userId, pinHash
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY userId, pinHash;
```

Comment: Thank you, tested it. Works the way I wanted. I could figure out I need a Group by, but missed the MIN(id) part.

Answer (score 0):

Your data

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
   id        INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,userId    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,seed      VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,assetType VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
  ,pinHash   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TEST
(id,userId,seed,assetType,pinHash) VALUES 
(1,110,'a12H','Bitcoin','q23es'),
(2,111,'r23s','Bitcoin','e2w12'),
 (3,111,'y36w','Ethereum','e2w12');
```

use `Row_number` function

```
SELECT id,
       userid,
       pinhash
FROM   (SELECT id,
               userid,
               seed,
               assettype,
               pinhash,
               Row_number ()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY userid, pinhash
                   ORDER BY id ASC ) rn
        FROM   test) T
WHERE  rn = 1
```